# Method invocation "vibrate" may produce java.lang.NullPointerException warning after updating to Android Studio 3

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

After updating to Android Studio 3.0, I'm getting this warning every time I try to use vibrate():

> Method invocation 'vibrate' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Here's my code:

```
package com.gavinsappcreations.vibratortest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(100);

    }
}
```

I've included the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Also, the code works on my device.

Comment: Show your detail code and error logcat info .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just remove the warning doing.

```
if(vibrator != null) {
   vibrator.vibrate(100);
}
```

Check Nikolas's comment.

Comment: Thanks! I was just confused because I don't recall this warning ever showing up in prior Android Studio versions.

Comment: While the not null check fixes the warning, the assumption about "doesn't have a VIBRATOR_SERVICE" is plain wrong. Your IDE just performs static code analysis, and does so more restrictive then your former IDE might have.

Comment: Effectively, you're right. After reading the documentation of this object, there is a method hasVibrator() which implies that this object is never null.

Comment: Although, I have a developer console error log that says NullPointerException when using vibrate, on a Galaxy S8+, which definitely has a vibrator. Maybe there's a setting to restrict vibration access?

Comment: I got such a crash from Samsung Galaxy Tab A (2016)
on Android 8.1 (SDK 27), so I've set null check there.